# Converting numpy array to single integer

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am a new Python user, and am struggling with what is seemingly a very easy problem — yet I cannot seem to solve it.  The problem is that I created an array from np that contains a single value.

```
In:   distance_index
Out:  (array([14], dtype=int64),)

In:   type(distance_index)
Out:  tuple
```

So, my question is simple...I need to grab the value of 14 from the array so that I can use it in another part of the code.

Comment: `distance_index[0][0]`?

Comment: Do you know the concept of indexing?

Comment: I am working on it...why do you need the second [0]?

Comment: That isn't an array, that is a `tuple` with a single element, which is the array. That is what you seem to not be grokking

Comment: @chrisz, wow...I have a long way to go...THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

To get any index of your array just use "array[index]". Keep in mind arrays start at 0

```
print(distance_index[0])
```

However, as @Christian Dean points out, this question deals with an array in a tuple. So you need:

```
print(distance_index[0][0])
```

Comment: `distance_index` is a tuple itself, containing the Numpy array. You need to index the tuple, _then_ index the Numpy array. In other words: `distance_index[0][0]`.

Comment: @Christian, I realize now just hiw much I have yet to learn about programming.  This is definately a steep learning curve.  As a sde note, this part of my code now works!  Thank you for your patience and gracious support.

Comment: Glad I could help @KevinDow.